# Simulated Annealing Implementation in C++

Tags: c++

I am interested in implementing simulated annealing, and my current gives the wrong output. I believe my understanding of it is flawed. Could someone help and explain how this implementation is wrong? dist is an array of my conditional probabilities.

```
int idx=0;
double value = dist[0];
for (int ix = 1; ix < ITERS ; ixx ){
    double temp = (1/500)*((1/ix)- (1/ITERS));
    for(int m = 0; m < input.rows()-1; m++){
      double p = transitionProbability(dist[m], dist[m+1],temp);
        if (p > unifRand() ) {
            if (dist[m+1] < value)
                value = dist[m+1];
                idx = m+1;      
            }
        else {  
      idx = m;
      }
   }
}



double inline transitionProbability(double d0, double d1,double T) {

if (d0 > d1)
    { return 1; }

else 
    { return (exp(d0 - d1)/T);  }
}
```

Comment: For some specific input, what is the *expected* and *actual* output? Have you tried running in a debugger and stepping through it line by line to see what's happening?

Answer (score 1):

It would me more easy to answer your question if you can also describe what optimization problem you are trying to solve, and what are your data structures.

For example, what does "input.rows" refer to in your implementation?

The basic idea of SA is, at each iteration:

- make a random modification of the current solution
- compute the cost of the new solution
- set it as current solution (for next iteration) if it is accepted (using the transition probability function, which looks to be correct)

Comment: I am trying to optimize detection of curves in an image, where input.rows denote the number of pixels in a row

Comment: It is not clear to me how do you represent a solution in your code, how do you compute the cost of a given solution, and what modifications you make.
This link may help you if you are not used to this type of methods: http://katrinaeg.com/simulated-annealing.html

Comment: The cost is already computed in dist array, so I have a matrix of conditional probabilities

Comment: I do not understand the cost of what? 
What do you precisely mean by "cost"?
You mean of the cost one specific solution, of all possible solutions, or something else?

Comment: The cost of all possible solutions

Comment: I am trying to follow this algorithm http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~stewart/sltcv/handout-06.pdf

Comment: So to get the optimal solution, why can't you just scan the dist array and keep the best one?

Comment: I think that is what I am trying to do, but I am a little confused about having to different costs as specified in the algorithm

Comment: Be careful, as far as I understand it, the paper that you linked does not describe the simulated annealing algorithm. It is about image denoising, and presents some ideas of algorithms for this task. SA is just one among others, and is not developped at all in the paper. 

Simulated Annealing may not be what you need for your purpose (you can still look at the website I linked above to see what it can be used for).